# htaccess temporarily unavailable for specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-503

I have a specific folder for which I want to trigger a 503 response (maintenance).
The rest of my website should be accessible.

can this be easily done in htaccess?

I browsed the web but can only find information on how to do it for the whole website.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /503.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/503.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

PS: I also tried to find a more general tutorial on htaccess and this type of stuff so I can learn the basics and figure out things myself. But all I found was snippets and snippets and more snippets. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to just place above code in `/folder/.htaccess`** where you want to show 503 custom page. Otherwise your code looks fine. Just make sure `/503.php` exists.

Comment: Thanks, this worked except that it does not show my ErrorDocument. Somehow the server displays a default 503 page instead. I am running Apache on CentOS, pretty standard setup I believe. What can I do?

Comment: I tested it again it works on my Apache. Just make sure `/503.php` exists in root not in current folder. For keeping itside folder use `ErrorDocument 503 /folder/503.php`

Comment: For me it doesn't work. I think something is wrong with the settings. I will contact my provider. Thanks for the answer, at least the 503 http response header is being sent like this!